# ConfigureScene with NavigatorIOS

Tags: react-native, navigator-ios

Is there a way to configure transitioning of scenes with NavigatorIOS? or does it only have a default floatFromRight property. I have,

```
this.props.navigator.push({
component : component,
title: 'hello',
// configuring the transition type 
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use other animations , see here: [navigator configurescene](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/navigator.html#configurescene)

You have all these:

- Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight "DEFAULT"
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJumpFromRight
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalUpSwipeJump
- Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump

Example:

```
<Navigator
   initialRoute={{id: 'Home'}}
   renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}
   configureScene={(route, routeStack) =>
      Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump
   }
/>
```

Comment: I know about Navigator. I'm asking for NavigatorIOS